# UTF8 Encoding changes data Format

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to get the output of a command in PowerShell and encode it and then decode it again to receive the results of the said command as shown.

```
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$bytes = $enc.GetBytes((Invoke-Expression "net users"))
$enc.GetString($bytes)
```

However, the result comes out malformed as opposed to the original `net users` command. I've tried changing the encodings to ASCII and Unicode and still the result is malformed.

Any ideas on how to maintain the formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't caused by the encoding, but because PowerShell will mangle the command output unless you force it into a string:

```
$bytes = $enc.GetBytes((Invoke-Expression "net users" | Out-String))
```

You don't need `Invoke-Expression` BTW. This will work as well:

```
$bytes = $enc.GetBytes((net users | Out-String))
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785243/45375):

**Invoking an external command returns the output lines as an *array* of strings.**

Because `Encoding.GetBytes()` expects a *single* string as input, **the array was implicitly coerced to a single string, in which case PowerShell joins the array elements using the *space* character**, so the original line formatting was lost; e.g.:

```sh
PS> [string] 1, 2, 3
1 2 3   # single string containing the array elements joined with spaces
```

**Piping to `Out-String`**, as in Ansgar's answer, prevents creation of the array and **returns the external command output as a *single* string**.

```sh
PS> (1, 2, 3 | Out-String | Measure-Object).Count
1          # Out-String output a single string
```

Another option would be to **join the array elements with newlines on demand** (you won't see the difference in the console, but you do get a single, multi-line output string with this technique):

```sh
PS> (net users) -join "`n"            # or, more robustly: [environment]::NewLine
```

**Note:** With this technique, the output string will not have a *trailing* newline, unlike when you use `Out-String`.
`Out-String` *always* appends a trailing newline, which can be undesired.

---

Alternatively, **you can tell PowerShell what encoding to expect from an external command by setting `[Console]::OutputEncoding`** (temporarily):

However, that is only necessary if you know the external utility to use an output encoding other than the default (your system's active OEM code page) - and I doubt that that's necessary for `net users`; that said, here's how it would work:

```sh
$prevEnc = [Console]::OutputEncoding 
[Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$str = net users | Out-String  # `net users` output is now properly decoded as UTF-8
[Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEnc
```