# Use Powershell to import website with Chinese domain

Tags: powershell, encoding, import, appcmd

I’m trying use PowerShell to add website from xml file.

When I just use CMD  command

```
appcmd  add site /in < test.xml
```

The binding of website is 「測試.com.tw」and everything be fine.

But when I use Powershell

```
Get-Content test.xml | appcmd add site /in
```

The binding will be 「???.com.tw」

Even if I change chcp to 65001 or use “-encoding utf8” when get-content,  but nothing change and still can’t correct import a website with Chinese domain.

My server is 2008 R2 and Powershell 1.0

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell uses the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6#outputencoding) to determine the character encoding to use when sending data to *external programs* (such as `appcmd`) via the pipeline (what the external program receives via stdin, the standard input stream).

In Windows PowerShell, `$OutputEncoding` defaults to ASCII(!), meaning that only characters in the 7-bit ASCII are correctly sent, and all characters outside that range are replaced with *literal* `?` characters.

**You must set `$OutputEncoding` to match the encoding that `appcmd` expects when reading from stdin**; according to your feedback, UTF-8 must be used:

```
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new($false) # BOM-less UTF-8

Get-Content test.xml | appcmd add site /in 

# Consider restoring the previous $OutputEncoding value
```

Note: The above assumes that `Get-Content` properly recognizes the encoding of `test.xml` when reading from it; if not, use its `-Encoding` parameter to specify the file's encoding explicitly.

Complementarily, **when PowerShell *reads* output *from* external programs, it is the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` that determines how the output is decoded** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787047/45375).